# PickIfContains type to pick in an object whether the keys belongs to the object definition or not

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to build a type that will Pick any key of an object if the object contains the key (independently of the fact the key is defined on the type of the object or not. (`Pick` needs keys that belongs to the type of the object)

```js
type PickIfContains <T, K extends string []> = {
  [P in K [number]]: P extends keyof T ? T [P] : never
}

type A = {a: number, b: number}
type B = PickIfContains <A, ['a', 'c']>
// GIVEN: {a: number, c: never}
// EXPECTED: {a: number}
```

How can I remove in the resulting type the keys that are set to `never` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I believe you can do something more simple than [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70477486/2398593)

```
type PickIfContains<T, K extends string> = {
    [L in Extract<keyof T, K>]: T[L]
}
```

[Live demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYEkBmBhA9gO2AQzhwGcAeAFQBooBpKCAD2AhwBNipjgAnIgcwB8UALxQA3gFgAUFFlQA2gBkoRKAFEm3fAmCkkEEFjRQqtAQF0AXCaXnpAX2nTQkKAEER4qPms4ArgC2AEYQ3NRBvoEhYVAI1ly8OHxQjlIu0ABCnvDI6Nh4hCSkbtQA5PilUAA%20UKUIlTWlEKUCTlJAA)

Answer (score 0):

I did found an answer
It's just a tad verbose

```js
type PickIfContains <T, K extends string []> = {
  [
    P in {
      [P in K [number]]: P extends keyof T ? P : never
    } [K [number]]
  ]: T [P]
}
```

If anyone has a better solution don't hesitate ;)